# Create a radar chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, radar-chart, ggradar

I have been struggling a ton today to make a radar chart in R.
I just have an one line data nad I want to show it in nice radar chart instead of a line plot

my data is

```
data=tibble("AAAP family"=15,"ABC super family"=42,"ACA"=6, "ACBP60s"=4,"AGC Family"=12,"AS2 family"=5,"Acyl Lipid Metabolism Family"=167)
```

I have tried

```
library(fmsb)

  radarchart(data,  axistype=1 , 
             
             #custom polygon
             pcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9) , pfcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5) , plwd=4 , 
             
             #custom the grid
             cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="grey", caxislabels=seq(0,20,5), cglwd=0.8,
             
             #custom labels
             vlcex=0.8 
  )
```

and many other libraries, but zero success. Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: A simple search on: "r radar chart" turns up good solutions: https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/beautiful-radar-chart-in-r-using-fmsb-and-ggplot-packages/  Usually good to search first before you post here to save yourself the turnaround time.

Comment: So what about that didn't work? Try to be more specific than "zero success," as well as including what libraries didn't work and why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `ggradar`:

```r
# adding code for installing ggradar
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("ricardo-bion/ggradar", dependencies = TRUE)

# load the library in global environment
library(ggradar)

names(data) <- gsub(' ', '_', names(data))
ggradar::ggradar(data, grid.max = 200, axis.label.size = 3)
```

[image]